# Printing out an element of a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like so:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,4]
c = [3,4,5]
lists = [a,b,c]
```

I want to print out the name of the first element in "lists" like so:

```
print lists[0]
a
```

But of course python does not work like that and does this:

```
print lists[0]
[1,2,3]
```

How can I print out the name of lists[0] without printing the contents of lists[0]?

Comment: If you want the lists to have a name, you need to find another way to do it, like using a dictionary, or subclassing `list`. You're not putting `a` into the list, you're putting the object `a` refers to in the list.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The list has no "name". You have a variable which points to the same object, and the variable has a name. It is in theory possible to find that variable via `globals` or `locals` if it is in the same scope, but you should _never_ do that. If you need a name attached to that list, use a dictionary.

Comment: `lists = ['a', 'b', 'c']`?

Comment: I decided to use a dictionary and it works a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to use an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dlists = OrderedDict([('a', [1,2,3]), ('b', [2,3,4]), ('c', [3,4,5])])
print dlists.keys()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can lookup the scope to find names associate with the object that you are looking for.

```
def namesOf(x, scope=globals()):
  r = []
  for name, value in scope.iteritems():
    if value is x:
      r.append(name)
  return r


a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,4]
c = [3,4,5]

lists = [a,b,c]


print namesOf(lists[0], locals())
```

But do it just if you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

The best option seems to be to use a dictionary.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,4]
c = [3,4,5]
data = {'a':a,'b':b,'c':c}
```

And if I want to print out the name of the first list I can just do:

```
data.keys()[0] 
'a'
```